# Efficient way or replacing "a" with "an"?

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, nsregularexpression

In my most recent project I am dynamically constructing sentences, then after the fact going through my text to grammatically "clean things up". One task I have is to switch occurrences of "a" to "an" where the first letter of the next word is a vowel. For now, I'm only concerned with lowercase English language words, and am ignoring following words that begin with 'h'.

The solution I have in place now works, but it looks terribly inefficient and definitely will not scale should I want to support internationalization in the future.

```
    if ([destination rangeOfString:@" a "].location != NSNotFound) {
        destination = [destination stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" a a" withString:@" an a"];
        destination = [destination stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" a e" withString:@" an e"];
        destination = [destination stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" a i" withString:@" an i"];
        destination = [destination stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" a o" withString:@" an o"];
        destination = [destination stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" a u" withString:@" an u"];
    }
```

I check for the " a " case up front, just to skip the inefficiency of all those replacement lines to follow. I'm thinking there must be a way of doing this in a sleeker, more efficient manner, perhaps using regular expressions?

Comment: I know this is outside the scope of your question, but these types of issues with data quality are generally better suited for solutions involving the remediation of upstream datasources.

Comment: Before you go down this path, you'll want to write a lot of test cases. As you make this more efficient, it will be very easy to break functionality. Note that this also misses exceptions with leading u. "A uniform" but "an umbrella." I'm very curious what "internationalization" would mean in this case. Note that "sleeker" and "more efficient" are likely at odds. The most efficient approach would be by scanning the string one time, character by character, but probably is not "sleek" in the way that you mean it. (Agreed with esqew that you should focus on fixing this at sentence construction.)

Comment: The state-machine scanning solution should be very straightforward: iterate character by character, adjusting your state between "idle," "waiting for a" (which happens at the start and after a space), "waiting for space" (after a), waiting for "letter" (after space after a), and then if letter is a vowel, emit "an <letter>" otherwise emit "a <letter>". All other states: emit character. But you'll want a lot of test cases.

Comment: Agree with you there, Rob, on test cases. Yes, I can see how I would do this a character at a time, and have done this sort of thing in the past using traditional c-strings. But as I'm relatively new to Cocoa and objective-c I'm thinking I may be missing some capability of the Foundations classes I've yet to encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Foundation tool that could be helpful here is [`NSRegularExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression), along the regular expression lines you suggested.

Here's an example:

```
NSString* source = @"What is a apple doing in a toilet? A umbrella is in there too!";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b([Aa])( [aeiou])"
                              options:0
                              error:nil];
NSString* result = [regex
                     stringByReplacingMatchesInString:source
                     options:0
                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [source length])
                     withTemplate:@"$1n$2"];
```

A couple minor notes:

- The `options:0` and `error:nil` entries are just me punting on options that might be useful in the real-world use case.
- I added that word boundary (`\\b`), to catch what I imagine might be tricky post-punctuation occurrences of "a" (e.g. "It rained; a earthworm appeared."). [edit: whoops, I’m wrong, that was where I was thinking of an “A” *starting* a sentence.]

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Thanks Colin! This is exactly what I was looking for. regular expression pattern matching can sometimes be a black art and this helps tremendously.